# Unknown string format error when I try to clean the dataframe I'm working in

Tags: python, string, dataframe, time-series, data-cleaning

I am trying to setup the given data so I can analyze the timeseries data. I am new to coding, especially to Python.

With the code included, I keep getting error:
ParserError: Unknown string format: RegionType

but I'm not sure how to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciate it.

I have dataset

```py
df = pd.read_csv('http://files.zillowstatic.com/research/public_csvs/zhvi/Zip_zhvi_uc_sfr_month.csv', encoding='latin')
```

I have gotten furthest with the below code, but still get an error that I can't get past:

```
# Convert columns that have dates to datetime
def get_datetimes(df):
    return pd.to_datetime(df.columns.values[9:], format='%Y-%m')
df.columns = list(df.columns[:9]) + list(get_datetimes(df))
df.head()

# convert zip code to col names
df = df.set_index('RegionName')
# transpose time series matrices
df = df.T
# convert indices to date time
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first 9 indeces (RegionID, SizeRank, RegionName, RegionType, StateName, State, City, Metro, CountyName) are strings, so not a format that can be converted to `datetime`.

When you convert the indexes to datetime, what you need to do is something similar to what you already did when you converted the columns:

```py
# Convert columns that have dates to datetime
def get_datetimes(df):
    return pd.to_datetime(df.columns.values[9:], format='%Y-%m')
df.columns = list(df.columns[:9]) + list(get_datetimes(df))
df.head()

# convert zip code to col names
df = df.set_index('RegionName')
# transpose time series matrices
df = df.T
# convert indices to date time
df.index = list(df.index[:8]) + list(pd.to_datetime(df.index[8:]))
df.head()
```

However, I don't understand why you convert back and forth dates.
Your same final dataframe can be achieved only by adding the `RegionName` index, transposing the initial dataframe and converting to datetime:

```py
# convert zip code to col names

df2=pd.read_csv('http://files.zillowstatic.com/research/public_csvs/zhvi/Zip_zhvi_uc_sfr_month.csv', encoding='latin')
df2 = df2.set_index('RegionName').T
df2.index = list(df.index[:8]) + list(pd.to_datetime(df.index[8:]))

df.equals(df2) #True
```